# The difference between "Each cake's piece" and "Each piece of the cake"

Tags: word-choice, writing, ielts

**The difference between "Each cake's piece" and "Each piece of the cake".**

What's the correct option to use when writing IELTS writing task 1 discussing a pie chart?
Example:

> "As we can see in both charts, each piece of the cake / each cake's
> piece represents a source of power.."

Comment: A **pie chart** does not have pieces of cake. It has slices of the pie (the whole chart).

Answer (score 7):

"each piece of the cake" implies that there's one cake and refers to each piece of it.

"each cake's piece" suggests that there are multiple cakes, and you're talking about one piece of each of them.

You can also say "each cake piece" (without a possessive). This is not specific about how many cakes there are, but refers to all pieces of all cakes. When the context makes it clear that there is just one cake, it's the same as "each piece of the cake".

Comment: With "each piece of cake" (no _the_) also being equivalent to the last one.